# ROS service provider needs to subscribe to client topic

Tags: ros

So in ROS I have a server which provides a greetService in which new clients send their greeting requests and the reserver responds with something. The important part is that I want them to continue communicating, I have Anonymous=True for clients as I launch multiple instances of them. Let's say I want the client's topic to be CLIENTNAME_POSITION how can I get the server to subscribe and keep track of that? I'm using python by the way but a c++ response is alright too as I'm fluent in both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two services that the server will provide. They would be used by the client to register and unregister from the server.

When a client wants to register, it provides the topic name it will use to get the greetings within the service request. The server adds a new Publisher corresponding to the new client in a list (or a dictionary). To unregister the client sends the topic it was using and the server removes the corresponding Publisher in the list.